# Trigger Azure pipeline when pull request title updated

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm currently writing some custom pipelines for my team to enforce our versioning, commit & merge strategy standards, such as:

- Conventional Commit formatting on the merge commit
- Enforcing squash commits when merging in bug fixes and features
- etc

Is there a way to trigger this pipeline to run when a pull requests title is updated?

The workflow at the moment is quite strict:
When a dev creates their PR, it runs this pipeline automatically ensuring their PR title is correctly formatted, which then fails because:

1. The PR auto-complete policy wouldn't be set, meaning the merge commit and merge strategies are null when hitting the [Azure Pull Request REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull-requests?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)
2. The developer then needs to correct this and manually re-queue the pipeline

If their PR title is incorrect to begin with, they also need to re-run this pipeline.

Is this something that can be achieved?

Looking at the [Azure Trigger Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/triggers?view=azure-devops) I don't see anything immediately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Azure DevOps, currently it is not supported to trigger the pipeline when the **PR title changed** event occurs.

The PR triggers on Azure DevOps can only support below events:

- A PR is opened.
- Some new changes pushed to the source branch of the opening PR.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to trigger a pipeline automatically upon a PR title change. But I would like to suggest you to go with a **comment trigger**. Since developers anyway need to update the title, they can put a comment to the PR at the same time. That can trigger the pipeline with a minimum manual effort. Following comments can be used.

```
/azp run
/azp run <pipeline-name>
```

or

```
/AzurePipelines run
/AzurePipelines run <pipeline-name>
```

P.S. The one who comments on the PR should have at least write access on the repository to trigger the pipeline.

Comment: this is only correct if your repo is hosted on github. On Azure DevOps comment trigger do not work as mentioned in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/triggers?view=azure-devops)