# Azure DevOps Enforcing Pull Request Title

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have implemented an Azure Pipeline that checks if the pull request (PR) titles match the expected format when a PR is merged into the dev branch. The issue I'm facing is that even if the pipeline check passes, it is still possible to change the PR title directly on the Azure page after the check. If the title is changed and then 'Complete' is clicked to merge the PR, this action would violate the rule that the pipeline was meant to enforce.

Maybe use an Azure Service hook to check if the PR title has changed.
Or using Azure status check. In fact, I haven't thought of a solution yet.

Comment: This sounds like a process issue - it can't currently be enforced (unless you make a gate to check it). Before developing something - I would really ask - is it worth it?

Comment: Why is the PR title such a concern?

Answer (score 0):

> The issue I'm facing is that even if the pipeline check passes, it is still possible to change the PR title directly on the Azure page after the check.

Currently DevOps doesn't monitor on the Pull request title change. Changing PR title won't trigger a new pipeline, and it won't trigger webhook event.

Please check the [similar ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72745597/14996050) for your reference.

I can fully understand your requirement. You may submit a suggest ticket in the site: [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/AzureDevOps/suggest) to report this feature.

Comment: Before posing my question, I had already reviewed the similar ticket you provided to me. However, since that comment dates back more than a year ago, I would like to verify if there have been any new developments. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You are welcome @Jack. As the limitation still exists, you could raise the suggestion ticket following link above. Happy coding!